# freeing char pointer in c causes segfault

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

The subject says all, here's the relevant code written in a simple file.

```
char* fn = NULL;
SDL_Log("fn pre address is: %p\n",fn);
fn = get_resource("test.txt");
SDL_Log("fn pos address is: %p\n",fn);
//free(fn); <--this causes seg fault if I uncomment it

INFO: fn pre address is: 0x0
INFO: fn pre address is: 0x7fa882501a00
INFO: fn pos address is: 0x7fa882501a00

get_resource(const char* filename) {
    char* string = (char*)calloc(1, sizeof(strlen(res_dir) + strlen(filename)));
    //i also tried with strncpy
    //strncpy(string, res_dir, strlen(res_dir));
    //strncpy(string + strlen(res_dir), filename, strlen(filename));

    memcpy(string, "/usr/test/files", strlen(res_dir));
    memcpy(string + strlen("/usr/test/files"), filename, strlen(filename));
    string[strlen(filename) + strlen("/usr/test/files")] = '\0';
    return string;
}
```

getting the same behavior. If I free the allocated string I will get a seg fault. Also it doesn't always happen either which is strange.

Comment: OT: `string` is a bad name, also it is misleading as it's a *pointer* to the 1st element (a `char` here) of the memory allocated by the call to `calloc()`.

Comment: @alk also OT, but I find `string` to be a very appropriate name for a `char*`.

Comment: @MrLister on some abstraction level, `string` describes quite well what `char *` means, if it points to a "C string". But I'm with @alk here for two reasons: 1.) a "C string" is the sequence of bytes, not the pointer to it -- the sequence will evaluate to a pointer often (if it's an array or if you just use a *string literal*) and 2.) naming a variable like this just isn't expressive. It's like writing `int myInt = 42;` -- great, what do you make from *that* when reading code?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Sure, but in this case (the OP's example), the `string` is a local variable in a function that doesn't know the global meaning of the resource it's going to fetch. It would be impossible to be more descriptive than that! Also, in your second example, what would you rather suggest? `int  whatdoyougetifyoumultiplysixbynine`?

Comment: @MrLister `int whatsTheMeaningOfLifeUniverseAndEverything`. Note the camelCase. \*scnr\* :D and to get a bit serious again, I'd probably name it `fullPath` or something like this in OPs code :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Not too serious, please. Or if you are, I feel strongly that dromedaryCase, or, "headless camelCase", should be restricted to Java. C should use either lowercasealltheway, or RealCamelCase for public library functions.

Comment: @MrLister discussing naming guidelines can get quite exhausting quickly ;) just saying what you call "RealCamelCase" is typically called "PascalCase". But apart from that: being consistent is the most important, no matter what the guidelines are. "speaking names" is good practice, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this statement

```
char* string = (char*)calloc( 1, sizeof(strlen(res_dir) + strlen(filename)));
```

is incorrect. Expression

```
sizeof(strlen(res_dir) + strlen(filename))
```

is equivalent to

```
sizeof( size_t )
```

and can be equal either 4 or 8 depending on the used environment. More over this expression

```
sizeof(strlen(res_dir) + strlen(filename))
```

is **unevaluated**. That is function `strlen` **is not called** in this expression.

A correct statement can look like

```
char *string = calloc( strlen( res_dir ) + strlen( filename ) + 1, sizeof( char ) );
```

Take into acount that you need also reserve memory for the terminating zero.

However even this statement is incorrect.:)

Consider what you are trying to do

```
memcpy(string, "/usr/test/files", strlen(res_dir));
memcpy(string + strlen("/usr/test/files"), filename, strlen(filename));
```

As you passed string `"test.txt"` then you will get

```
"/usr/test/filestest.txt"
```

I think you mean instead the following

```
"/usr/test/files/test.txt"
```

If so then the memory allocation must look like

```
char *string = calloc( strlen( res_dir ) + strlen( filename ) + 2, sizeof( char ) );
```

In this case you could write simply

```
strcpy( string, "/usr/test/files" );
strcat( string, "/" );
strcat( string, filename );
```

and in this case statement

```
string[strlen(filename) + strlen("/usr/test/files")] = '\0';
```

must be removed.

Comment: Hmm not sure what to make from this? It's nice to see you clarify what `sizeof(strlen([foo]))` would actually evaluate to and also work out a bit more explicitly why a slash might be missing from the resulting path ... but did you really have to give basically the same answer again? Well, upvoting anyways as there *is* some explanation I didn't include myself.

Answer (score 8):

```
char* string = (char*)calloc(1, sizeof(strlen(res_dir) + strlen(filename)));
```

This line doesn't make *any* sense, `sizeof` is an operator for determining the storage size needed for a **type** or an expression of some type.(*)

What you want is something like:

```
char* string = calloc(1, strlen(res_dir) + strlen(filename) + 1);
```

Note the `+ 1` there, it reserves space for the terminating `0` byte in a c-style string. Also note casting of a `void *` pointer (as returned by `malloc()` and friends in C) doesn't make sense. It's necessary in C++, but in C, `void *` is the *generic pointer type* and implicitly converts to any other data pointer type.

Digging further into your code (as per alk's comment) ... I guess `res_dir` is just `"/usr/test/files"`? You might be missing a slash here (depending on the contents of your `filename`) but in general, for concatenating strings, there is already a function in the C language, declared in `string.h`. Just write something as simple as that:

```
char* string = calloc(1, strlen(res_dir) + strlen(filename) + 1);
strcpy(string, res_dir);
strcat(string, filename);
```

and you're done. Note you don't even need `calloc()` with this method, `malloc()` will do fine.

---

(*) adding here even a bit more explanation: You probably see `sizeof` quite often used with memory allocations, for obvious reasons. What you want is to reserve memory for the type `char`. And you want some count of `char`s to fit into this memory. So, the correct formula for that would be something like:

```
malloc( (strlen(res_dir) + strlen(filename) + 1) * sizeof(char) )
```

Then why leave out the `sizeof(char)`? That's because the size of a `char` is actually *defined* to be `1`. `x * 1` is still `x`, so no need to use `sizeof` here :)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the preferred way to concatenate C-"strings" is to use `strcat()`.

Comment: @alk sure, it's not in the scope of the question I guess, but I'll have a second look -- thanks.

Comment: @alk and thus, a little straight-forward answer grew to something like a "string and dynamic allocations handling primer" ... hehe. Hope it helps the OP, thanks for hinting on it.

Comment: I upvoted this answer but selected the one below because it was more thorough and gave me a clearer understanding of the root cause of my issue. It also used strncpy and strcat which I didn't really know about so it also helped me to understand how to better handle char arrays in c.